# MIN function returning multiple rows after adding column to SELECT

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to get the minimum value of `Price` together with product `Description` in the table `ProductVariation`.

[image]

When creating my query this way:

```
SELECT productId, MIN([price]) AS price
FROM ProductVariation
GROUP BY ProductId
```

It works as expected, grouping by `ProductId` and minimum value of `Price`:

| ProductId | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 299.99 |
| 6 | 299.99 |
| 7 | 299.99 |
| 8 | 199.99 |
| 9 | 299.99 |
| 10 | 299.99 |
| 11 | 159.99 |
| 12 | 159.99 |
| 13 | 189.99 |
| 14 | 189.99 |

However, when I add `Description` column to the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT productId, [Description], MIN([price]) AS price
FROM ProductVariation
GROUP BY ProductId, [Description]
```

It shows all rows, repeting `ProductId` column.

| ProductId | Description | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Natural | 299.99 |
| 6 | Cookies & Cream | 299.99 |
| 7 | Morango | 299.99 |
| 8 | Baunilha | 199.99 |
| 8 | Chocolate | 299.99 |
| 9 | Caramelo | 299.99 |
| 10 | Baunilha | 299.99 |
| 10 | Cookies & Cream | 399.99 |
| 10 | Morango | 399.99 |
| 11 | Baunilha | 199.99 |
| 11 | Morango | 159.99 |

How can I fix it to show **unique** `ProductId` values together with its `Description` like this?

| ProductId | Description | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Natural | 299.99 |
| 6 | Cookies & Cream | 299.99 |
| 7 | Morango | 299.99 |
| 8 | Baunilha | 199.99 |
| 9 | Caramelo | 299.99 |
| 10 | Baunilha | 299.99 |
| 11 | Morango | 159.99 |
| 12 | Baunilha | 159.99 |
| 13 | Caramelo | 189.99 |
| 14 | Morango | 189.99 |

And if you could explain why it's not working my way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) like [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to enumerate the rows in groupings (partitions) of the `ProductId`, sorted by the `Price` ascending, and then `SELECT` only the minimum `Price` row for each group.

For example:

```
WITH _ProductVariationsSorted AS
(
    SELECT 
        ProductId, 
        Description,
        Price,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY Price) AS SortId -- Generate a unique ID within each group of ProductId rows, sorted by the Price
    FROM dbo.ProductVariation
)

SELECT 
    ProductId, 
    Description,
    Price
FROM _ProductVariationsSorted
WHERE SortId = 1; -- Only return the rows with the lowest Price per ProductId grouping
```

Another approach (shoutout to Erik Darling for reminding me) is just straight up windowing the `MIN()` aggregate function. You'll also need to `DISTINCT` the rows. You may find this simplifies the code like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ProductId, 
    Description,
    MIN(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId) AS Price
FROM dbo.ProductVariation
```

And finally a third but similar approach is using the [`FIRST_VALUE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) window function as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ProductId, 
    Description,
    FIRST_VALUE(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY PRICE) AS Price
FROM dbo.ProductVariation
```

Though depending on your data size, and how your tables and indexes are architected, you may find one of these solutions more performant than the other. Always test accordingly.

---

One other important thing to note, is when using window functions, if there are *ties* for the value in the column you're windowing (within the same grouping), different window functions will handle those ties differently.

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function will nondeterministically choose one of the rows with the tie at random, when ordering by that tied value, to enumerate the rows. Then one of those ties will get filtered out further down when filtering on `WHERE SortId = 1`. The solution using `DISTINCT` and either the `SUM() OVER` or `FIRST_VALUE()` window functions, will include both tied rows.

For example, in your data, it looks like for `ProductId = 10` there are two rows with the same `Price = 399.99`, `Cookies & Cream` and `Morango`. Now this doesn't actually pose a problem in your data at the moment, because there's another row for `ProductId = 10` with a lower `Price`.

But let's pretend one day that variation is no longer sold and the row gets deleted. Now your lowest `Price` for `ProductId = 10` is `399.99` which is a tie between two variations. With the `ROW_NUMBER()` solution you'd only get one of those rows back at random, every time you ran the query. With the `SUM() OVER` or `FIRST_VALUE()` solutions, you'd get both rows back.

Depending on your goals, neither of these outcomes may be what you want. I.e. if you truly only wanted to show only 1 variation at a time, even when there's a tie in `Price` within the same `ProductId`, and you wanted it to reliably always be the same variation every time you ran the query.

To achieve this, you'd have to add a deterministic tie-breaker expression to the `ORDER BY` clause of the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function, for example, a uniquifying column such as the `Id` column. The code would then look like this: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY Price, Id) AS SortId`. And the rules of which row to return are now the one with the lowest `Price`, and in a tie for lowest `Price` then the row in the tie that has the lowest `Id` (theoretically was entered into the `ProductVariations` table first).

Comment: @gregoryp you should post a new question with appropriate details, and that'll maximize the chances of getting the best help.