# ROW_NUMBER() with OUTER APPLY

Tags: t-sql, functions, window-functions

I have a query that returns the lowest `Price` of a `ProductVariation` by using `ROW_NUMBER()` to enumerate the rows in groupings (partitions) of the `ProductId`, sorted by the `Price` ascending ([MIN function returning multiple rows after adding column to SELECT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320210/min-function-returning-multiple-rows-after-adding-column-to-select)).

```
SELECT 
   pv.Id AS VariationId, 
   pv.ProductId, 
   pv.[Description], 
   pv.Price, 
   pv.Stock,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pv.ProductId ORDER BY pv.Price, pv.Stock DESC) AS SortId
FROM ProductVariation pv
INNER JOIN Product p ON p.Id = pv.ProductId
WHERE p.CompanyId = @CompanyId
```

One `Product` can have multiple variations. Below I have my `ProductVariation` table.

[image]

This query works perfeclty and returns the following results:

| VariationId | ProductId | Description | Price | Stock | SortId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 149 | 97 | Yellow Fruits | 139.99 | 0.00 | 1 |
| 150 | 97 | Red Fruits | 139.99 | 5.00 | 2 |
| 151 | 97 | Green Apple | 139.99 | 20.00 | 3 |
| 152 | 98 | Peach Mango | 219.99 | 0.00 | 1 |
| 153 | 99 | Crazy Lemon | 169.99 | 1.00 | 1 |
| 154 | 99 | Arctic Ice | 169.99 | 3.00 | 2 |
| 155 | 99 | Paradise Punch | 169.99 | 3.00 | 3 |

However, now we have another table called `ProductValueConsultor` in which the consultor can update the `ProductVariation` price individually.

[image]

Inside `ProductValueConsultor` we have a row that updates the `ProductVariation` price to $149.00 for the id 149.

| StoreId | Price | ProductVariationId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 149.90 | 149 |

So now, I updated my query and added the `OUTER APPLY` operator to identify possible values on `ProductValueConsultor` table and show the updated prices.

```
SELECT 
   pv.Id AS VariationId, 
   pv.ProductId, 
   pv.[Description], 
   ISNULL(pValue.Price, pv.Price) Price, 
   pv.Stock,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pv.ProductId ORDER BY pv.Price) AS SortId
FROM ProductVariation pv
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ProductValueConsultor pvc
   WHERE pv.Id = pvc.ProductVariationId AND pvc.StoreId = @StoreId
) pValue
INNER JOIN Product p ON p.Id = pv.ProductId
WHERE p.CompanyId = @CompanyId
```

The `OUTER APPLY` operator worked perfeclty, showing the updated price for the `ProductVariation` id 149. However, the `ROW_NUMBER()` function broked, showing the sorted order for the original prices.

| VariationId | ProductId | Description | Price | Stock | SortId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 149 | 97 | Yellow Fruits | 149.99 | 0.00 | 1 |
| 150 | 97 | Red Fruits | 139.99 | 5.00 | 2 |
| 151 | 97 | Green Apple | 139.99 | 20.00 | 3 |
| 152 | 98 | Peach Mango | 219.99 | 0.00 | 1 |
| 153 | 99 | Crazy Lemon | 169.99 | 1.00 | 1 |
| 154 | 99 | Arctic Ice | 169.99 | 3.00 | 2 |
| 155 | 99 | Paradise Punch | 169.99 | 3.00 | 3 |

How can I fix this query to apply the `ROW_NUMBER()` function on the updated values by the `OUTER APPLY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `ORDER BY` in the row-number

```
SELECT 
   pv.Id AS VariationId, 
   pv.ProductId, 
   pv.[Description], 
   ISNULL(pValue.Price, pv.Price) Price, 
   pv.Stock,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY pv.ProductId
          ORDER BY ISNULL(pValue.Price, pv.Price)) AS SortId
FROM ProductVariation pv
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) pvc.*
    FROM ProductValueConsultor pvc
    WHERE pv.Id = pvc.ProductVariationId
      AND pvc.StoreId = @StoreId
) pValue
INNER JOIN Product p ON p.Id = pv.ProductId
WHERE p.CompanyId = @CompanyId;
```

The `TOP (1)` is suspicious as it has no `ORDER BY`. Assuming `ProductValueConsultor` is actually a many-many join table, you should always have exactly one row anyway so it's not necessary to add `TOP (1)`. Otherwise add an `ORDER BY` to the `APPLY`